# Suzuki and solvability of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups, solvable-groups

I read this theorem in the article which Antonio Beltran, I don't understand why prove this theorem:

"if a group $G$ satisfies $ν_{3}(G) = 1$ and has no composition factor isomorphic to the simple group $Sz(q)$, then G is solvable."

(which $ν_{p}(G)$ be the number of Sylow $p-$subgroups of $G$,  and the only non-abelian simple finite groups whose
order is not divisible by 3 are the Suzuki simple groups, Sz(q), with $q = 2^r$ and r > 1 odd).

I would be very thankful if you showed me ideas to prove.

Comment: If $P$ is a Sylow $3$, then you know that $P\unlhd G$. Obviously $P$ is solvable. $G/P$ is either solvable or has a non-abelian simple composition factor $H$. In the latter case $\gcd(3,|H|)=1$, so $H$ is Suzuki according to the fact you cited (I didn't know about that, but I'm mostly ignorant about the Classification).

Comment: i don't know why "G/P is either solvable or has a non-abelian simple composition factor H".

Comment: $G/P$ is solvable if and only if its composition factors are all abelian.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask this problem again. I don't understand  this line "G/P has a non-abelian simple composition factor H ". I'm not sure this.

Comment: The definition of *solvable* (or one of the properties equivalent to it) is that all the composition factors are abelian. What is your definition of *solvable*?